# iterations in document.ready (function) in jquery , d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

my data looks like this:

```
var IDData = JSON.stringify([["node/105173", "node/38180995", "Agent", "Customer", "1379644.0", 1, 264.0, "1374903"]...]
```

Every row of data follows the same format. But the length of rows of the array arrays is not fixed. I am trying to plot graphs using this data using d3.js.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    console.log(IDData);
    var galData = JSON.parse(IDData);
    need a way here to iterate through the data so that
    var startnodes = galData[0][0],galData[1][0]....galdata[n][0]
    where n is the length of the array
    var endnodes = galData[0][1],galData[1][1],galData[2][1]...galData[n][1]


    var nodetype = galData[0][2],galData[1][2],galData[2][2]....galData[n][2]

    var Paytime = galData[0][3],galData[1][3]..galdata[n][3]
    var TXN_COUNT = galdata[0][4],galData[1][4],galData[2][4]...galData[n][4]
    var Total_Amt = galData[0][5],galData[1][5],galData[2][5]...galData[n][5]

    var SendTime = galData[0][6],galData[1][6]...galData[n][6]

    makegraph(startnodes,endnodes)
```

var `nodetype` is a node attribute and var `Paytime`,`TXN_COUNT`,`Total_Amt`,`SendTime` are link attributes.

Not at all much familiar with d3.js and did not find a easy way to iterate .

Comment: what's up with the commas? are these supposed to be arrays or..?

Comment: @Pamblam that is a fair point . I actually do not know how to save those results. SO I used commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var IDData = JSON.stringify([["node/105173", "node/38180995", "Agent", "Customer", "1379644.0", 1, 264.0, "1374903"],["node/105173", "node/38180995", "Agent", "Customer", "1379644.0", 1, 264.0, "1374903"],["node/105173", "node/38180995", "Agent", "Customer", "1379644.0", 1, 264.0, "1374903"]]);
var galData = JSON.parse(IDData);

var startnodes = [],
    endnodes = [],
    nodetype = [];

// If array
galData.map(function(e,i){
    startnodes.push(e[0]);
    endnodes.push(e[1]);
    nodetype.push(e[2]);
});


console.log(startnodes);
console.log(endnodes);
console.log(nodetype);

// If string
startnodes = startnodes.join(',');
endnodes = endnodes.join(',');
nodetype = nodetype.join(',');

console.log(startnodes);
console.log(endnodes);
console.log(nodetype);
```

Does't cover all but you should get the picture.

Comment: @marcinek Let me try it. And how do I assign properties or attributes to links?

Comment: Unfortunately I never used d3.js :/ - this will just create the variables as strings or arrays as you wanted.